# How can I differ between manual and automatic scrolling in NSScrollView/NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I subclassed NSTextView and added support for automatic scrolling in a userdefineable time.
Now I want to detect, if the user manually scrolls, while the view is scrolling automatically.
Then I want to immediately stop automatic scrolling, until the user stops his action and then I want to start scrolling again from the new position.

I want to do this in such a matter, that the user can move around without a stuttering view.

I use boundsDidChangeNotification to calculate the scrolling position (playtime) and show it in a label, but I can't use it to detect the user manual scrolling, because it is also pushed by the automatic scrolling...

Would be very nice, if anyone has an idea ;-)

Thanks in advance

Gerald